# SSLHandshakeException when trying to connect to host

Tags: java

I am using the weblogicserver and I have enabled HTTPS connector.

I have a standalone Java program which connects to a site say, "xyz.com" and fetches me json over HTTPS. But when I try to run the same program on the server, it throws `SSLHandshakeException`.

Comment: Please post the relevant code that can be used to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Post the stacktrace...Have you added the certificate into weblogic trust store "cacerts"?

What are your java_options settings?If not set then try something similar to below

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/weblogic92/server/lib/c‌​acerts ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
```

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1290)
     at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513)
     at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1177)
     at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1149)
     at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
     at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$1.run(JaSSLEngine.java:68)
     at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:734)

Comment: set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dlaunch.main.class=%SERVER_CLASS% -Dlaunch.class.path="%CLASSPATH%" -Dlaunch.complete=weblogic.store.internal.LockManagerImpl -cp %WL_HOME%\server\lib\pcl2.jar "-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore=/weblogic92/server/lib/c‌​acerts ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"